# How to use the symbol %, &, = in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is the batch file I wrote to rename files. The problem I get is that if the file name includes one of the following symbol, the script does not work. `%` `&` `=`

```vb
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set file="C:\Users\Desktop\newdocument.txt"

SET file1=%file: =%
FOR /f %%i IN ("%file1%") DO (
  set fileextension=%%~xi
)
REN %file% "newname%fileextension%"
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you provide an example of how you're using this batch file?

Comment: Thank you for your response.This batch files want to rename all the type of files with the same extensions.So,first I took the file extension from the file path and concatenate it with the new file name,Those things are working fine,but the problem now is,For example if the file name is "%copy",the batch file,which i wrote is not working

Comment: @Suba Please provide relevant example of what does not. I showed you that it works. And now again: `copy nul "%copy" & dir "%copy" /B & REN "%copy" "renamed-file.txt" & dir "renamed*" /B & del "renamed*.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows you how to work the character substitution.
Please just open cmd instead of clicking on batch-file, navigate in the directory where is your script and run the script.

```vb
@echo off
setlocal

set "mydir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
pushd %mydir%

REM creating some empty files with space in file name
REM Here, you must escape the character '%' by doubling.
REM _somefile with % .txt
copy nul "_somefile with %%  &  =  21 .txt"
copy nul "_somefile with %%  &  =  22 .txt"
copy nul "_somefile with %%  &  =  23 .txt"


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir _somefile*with*.txt /s /B') do (
    set "newname=%%~nxi"
    echo REN "%%i" "!newname: =!"
)
endlocal
popd
pause
exit /b 0
```

Note I added an instance `pause`.

Output:

```vb
REN "_somefile with %  &  =  21 .txt" "_somefilewith%&=21.txt"
REN "_somefile with %  &  =  22 .txt" "_somefilewith%&=22.txt"
REN "_somefile with %  &  =  23 .txt" "_somefilewith%&=23.txt"
```

**Edit:** I updated the example with the characters that you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply,but my problem is not this.The above batch files want to rename all the type of files with the same extensions.So,first I took the file extension from the file path and concatenate it with the new file name,Those things are working fine,but the problem now is,For example if the file name is "%copy",the the batch file,which i wrote is not working

Comment: @Suba please show us the errors you getting. Files before renaming and files after renaming and errors that occurs. All of this in your edited question post.

Comment: For the above batch file,the rename can be done nicely.but if i add the source file name with the " %"sign,it's giving error as follows."The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: @Suba Please grab again the script, I have edited 30 min ago. Or see what I changed in the revision. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32644103/revisions