# Batch script to rename files which are having special character in their file names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a batch script to rename a file,which is having special characters in it's file name.
Example:  "My%Document"
If this example is my file name ,how can i rename it using batch script?

Comment: Why are you asking almost [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32643692/5047996) twice??

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience,i need some clear answer.

Comment: Please provide your code which you are having trouble with;

Comment: ren "file" "newname"  .if the filename is "f%" ,how can i double the % sign automatically?

Answer (score 1):

For defining a file path (or any string in general) containing special characters in an environment variable, use `set` where the entire assignment expression is enclose in `""`:

```
rem DEFINE PATH: C:\Root\dir=sub\foo&bar^\100%!
set "FILEPATH=C:\Root\dir=sub\foo&bar^\100%%!"
```

The only thing is you have to double all `%` to `%%`, as illustrated in the above.

To use such a file path (or string in general) for any command, you need to use delayed expansion. That way you "fool" the command interpreter.

Putting all this together, the following should work:

```
rem DEFINE PATH: C:\Root\dir=sub\foo&bar^\100%!
set "FILEPATH=C:\Root\dir=sub\foo&bar^\100%%!"
rem DEFINE NEW NAME: new=name%
set "FILENEWN=new=name%%"    

rem RENAME FILE
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ren "!FILEPATH!" "!FILENEWN!"
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,but i need to double the % sign automatically,not manually.

Comment: Note that the values of the variables do not contain the doubled `%`; so you only need to do that if you mention the file path in the script literally; if you get the file paths by another command (for example `dir /B My?Doc*`, found path is `My%Document`), doubling the `%` is not necessary;