# Batchfile to search a string in the filepath

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wan to search for a specific string in the file-path and double that particular string.

Example: if my filepath is `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\g%h.txt`
I want to search and get the `%` symbol and I need to double it like this `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\g%%h.txt`

How to do this with batch file?

Comment: Any reason to add `%` in the name? You should remove them because you will encounter problems if you pass the script a second time on these files.

Comment: yea I need to rename some files using batch script, which are having `%` symbol with in their name.

Comment: As I mentioned in your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648943/batch-script-to-rename-files-which-are-having-special-character-in-their-file-na/32650134#comment53225008_32650134), the doubling of `%` is only requited when a string like your file path contains `%` signs; when you assign such a string to a variable, the variable itself does not need to contain the doubled `%` signs...

Comment: Are you saying to assign the file path to a variable?,I tried like that,but that's not working.

Comment: @xyz, I'm trying to say that if the string containing `%` is _literally_ mentioned in your batch script, the `%` need to be doubled; however if the string is stored in an environment variable, the variable value should _not_ contain the doubled `%` signs; when you write `set "VAR=pre%%post"` in your script, there is the string mentioned _literally_, so the `%` are doubled here; but the variable `VAR` will contain the value `pre%post`, so _single_ `%` only; putting your posts together, I think you are confusing that...

Answer (score 0):

in batchfiles, you have to escape some special chars, so cmd knows NOT to treat them as "special". A percent-sign is escaped with another percent-sign:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  set name=%%i
  echo old name: !name!
  set name=!name:%%=%%%%!
  echo new name: !name!
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much,This code is working fine.But I need to give a specific file.how can I give that here?

Comment: `@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion set file=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\r%h.txt for %%i in (%file%) do ( set name=%%i echo old name: !name! set name=!name:%%=%%%%! echo new name: !name! )` I set like this,but the problem now is, in output,in the old name,it's sayinfg file name is "rh.txt" –  xyz 48 mins ago

Comment: you have to double the `%` with your `set` command to get a single `%` in the value

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample to match any txt that contain one or more `%`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt ^|findstr /i "%%"') do ( set file=%%i
  rem Here to remove every % in the name.
  echo ren "!file!" "!file:%%=!"
)
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In batch files as it was mentioned above you have to escape `%` sign with another `%` sign and file names are no exception. So instead of `set file=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\r%h.txt` you must use `set file=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\r%%h.txt`.

I wrote a separate batch file that accept two arguments: the first one is naming pattern and the second one is a symbol that needs to be doubled. So, for instance, if you want to double character "r" in all .txt files in the current directory you type
`<nameOfTheBatchFile> *.txt r` in the command line. Or in your case you can go with 
`<nameOfTheBatchFile> C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\r%h.txt %`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "namingPattern=%1"
set "charToDouble=%2"
for %%i in (%namingPattern%) do (
    set "curName=%%i"
    set newName=!curName:%charToDouble%=%charToDouble%%charToDouble%!
    if "!curName!" neq "!newName!" (
        echo Renaming !curName! -^> !newName!
        ren "!curName!" "!newName!"
    )
)
```